# What is the most efficient way to fill a QVector with data?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlist, qvector

I use `QList`s all over my code. According to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html and the linked page http://marcmutz.wordpress.com/effective-qt/containers/ `QVector` "should always be the first choice", or one shouldn't use `QList` at all, as long as one doesn't handle Qt API functions taking or returning a `QList`.

So I now think about to replace all the `QList`s and `QStringList`s in my code with `QVector`s (which should be no problem at all).

But what is the most efficient way to fill a `QVector` with data? There are three options:

```
QVector<sometype> vector;
for (whatever) {
    vector.append(someting)
}
```

This it what I currently do with most of my `QList`s. But often, I know how many elements the vector will have, and a `QVector` can be initialized with a given length or told how many elements it will have. So I can either do:

```
QVector<sometype> vector(count);
int i = 0;
for (whatever) {
    vector.insert(i++, something);
}
```

or:

```
QVector<sometype> vector;
vector.reserve(count);
for (whatever) {
    vector.append(something);
}
```

So which one is the most efficient approach?

Comment: 3 is more efficient than 1, but 2 and 3 are similar (I would guess), 3 wins on simplicity though

Comment: Note that 2) doesn't do what you think.  It creates a `QVector<sometype>` with `count` elements and then inserts further elements into that `QVector` within the loop.  i.e. you probably want `vector[i] = something` rather than `vector.insert(i++, something)`.

Comment: [std::fill](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) exist and makes it quite clear what you are doing and is quite efficient.

Comment: "void QVector::insert(int i, const T &value) Inserts value at index position i in the vector." So I think it does what I think, it replaces the default constructed values with the real ones, doesn't it?